# Program doesn't run

Tags: python

code stops in the middle. Please help
After taking all inputs the code stops while caluculating the caluculation part

```
i=float(input(print('enter the number of nodes')))
T0=float(input(print('Enter the first boundary condition')))
Tn=float(input(print('Enter the second boundary condition')))
a=float(input(print('Enter the Thermal cunductivity value')))
Ti=float(input(print('Enter the initial condition')))
n=float(input(print('Enter the number of time steps')))
dt=float(input(print('Enter the change in time dt')))
k=0
T=[]
T.append(T0)
while k!=i:
    T.append(Ti)
    k+=1
T.append(Tn)
print(T)
k=0
dx=1/(i+1)
while k!=n:
    j=0
    while j!=len(T):
        y=(a*dt/(dx**2))*(T[j-1]+T[j+1])+(1-2*((a*dt)/(dx**2)))*T[j]
        T.append(y)
        j+=1
    print(T)
    k+=1
```

Comment: Correct your code, remove `print` as argument of `input`. ` `i=float(input('enter the number of nodes'))`

Comment: i've changed the code  T.append(y) to T[j]=y. Then it's working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's rewrite your code using some simple Python features. (I'll leave advanced features for next year. ;-)

First, know the difference between integers and floats. A float is what you use if you expect to have a decimal point and do precise math. Part of programming is trying REALLY hard not to use floats unless you have to - floating point numbers take up more space, and they make your program run slower about 99% of the time.

Second, `raw_input([prompt])` takes a string to use as a prompt. No `print` required. (This becomes `input()` in Python 3.)
So:

```
i=float(input(print('enter the number of nodes')))
T0=float(input(print('Enter the first boundary condition')))
Tn=float(input(print('Enter the second boundary condition')))
a=float(input(print('Enter the Thermal cunductivity value')))
Ti=float(input(print('Enter the initial condition')))
n=float(input(print('Enter the number of time steps')))
dt=float(input(print('Enter the change in time dt')))
```

becomes:

```
num_nodes = int(input("Enter the number of nodes: "))
boundary1 = float(input("Enter the first boundary condition: "))
boundary2 = float(input("Enter the second boundary condition: "))
conductivity = float(input("Enter the thermal conductivity: "))
initial_cond = float(input("Enter the initial condition: "))
num_ticks = int(input("Enter the number of time steps: "))
delta_t = float(input("Enter the change in time, dT: "))
```

Now, let's initialize some stuff:

```
k=0
T=[]
T.append(T0)
while k!=i:
    T.append(Ti)
    k+=1
T.append(Tn)
print(T)
k=0
```

From this code, `k=0` to `k=0` tells me that k is just used as a loop counter. The loop is just appending the same value over and over to the T list. Also, you are using `T=[]` and then immediately `T.append(T0)`. Python already has a cool syntax for those things. But what is the T list for? Also, do the boundaries count against the number of nodes? Should they?

```
T = ( [boundary1] 
    + [initial_cond] * num_nodes 
    + [boundary2]
    )
```

Now we get to the last part of the code:

```
k=0
dx=1/(i+1)
while k!=n:
    j=0
    while j!=len(T):
        y=(a*dt/(dx**2))*(T[j-1]+T[j+1])+(1-2*((a*dt)/(dx**2)))*T[j]
        T.append(y)
        j+=1
    print(T)
    k+=1
```

Again with using `k` as a loop counter! There is a Pythonic way around that, too, but let's look inside the loop, where we see `j` also used as a loop counter. But at least `j` gets re-used as an index! We have an idiom for indexing, too.

In Python, when you want to loop *some number of times* you can use `range([start=0], stop, [step=1])`. By default, you get values `0 .. n-1`.

```
time_sec = 0.0
for t in range(num_ticks):
    time_sec += delta_t
```

Now, let's look at `dx`. I see you define it here:

```
dx=1/(i+1)
```

And you use it here:

```
y=(a*dt/(dx**2))*(T[j-1]+T[j+1])+(1-2*((a*dt)/(dx**2)))*T[j]
```

And that's all. But if we take apart that formula, and add a set of parens to handle the line-breaks, and some spaces, we get this:

```
y = (
              ( a*dt /(dx**2))   * (T[j-1] + T[j+1])
    +(1 - 2 * ((a*dt)/(dx**2)) ) * T[j]
    )
```

You never use `dx` without using `a*dt/dx**2`. So let's get rid of `dx` and replace it with that larger computation!

```
adt_per_dx2 = a * dt / (1 / (i+1)) ** 2
```

Which factors to:

```
adt_per_dx2 = a * dt * (i+1)**2
```

**Are you sure about that formula?**

Regardless, it changes the math to:

```
y = adt_per_dx2 * (T[j-1] + T[j+2]) + (1 - 2 * adt_per_dx2) * T[j]
```

Which I think is:

```
y = T[j] + (T[j-1] - T[j]) * adt_per_dx2 + (T[j+1] - T[j]) * adt_per_dx2
```

I wanted to get back to this because we can optimize with it. (Remember when I said floating point ops were expensive?)

Let's put that on hold for a minute, and look at `T`. When you start, I think T looks like a "material." That is, it looks like there is a boundary, and then some internal nodes, and then another boundary. Almost like you were modeling the temperature of a piece of material at different points throughout the thickness.

But then you append to the T list. Which makes the material thicker? Or just means you have a bug, and you should be *replacing* values instead of appending to the end of the list.

I'll try replacing values. You can tell me later if I got this wrong. (I'm guessing here, at what you're trying to do.)

Also, consider this:

```
lst = [1,2,3]
index = 0
print(lst[index-1] + lst[index] + lst[index+1])
```

If you feed that into Python, you'll get `6`. Why?

Because `lst[-1]` pulls the last item from the list! Special magic Python syntax! In this case, probably not what you wanted. In this case, I think you don't want to range from `0` up to `len(T)`. Instead, you want to range across the internal nodes and leave the boundaries alone. (Or, maybe you want to add some other values beyond the boundaries. You'll have to tell me.)

So we need to process just the *internal* nodes, and ignore the boundaries. Fortunately, the `range()` function takes a *start* parameter! But remember that it stops short of the *stop* argument. In this case we need to add one:

```
T_new = T[:] # Make a copy of T

for j in range(1, num_nodes+1):
    T_new[j] = ( T[j] 
           + (T[j-1] - T[j]) * adt_per_dx2 
           + (T[j+1] - T[j]) * adt_per_dx2
           )
T = T_new   # Replace the old T with the new T.
```

I did the T vs. T_new thing so that computing intermediate results wouldn't affect the subtractions (T[j-1] - T[j]).

Now, let's optimize a little bit. Notice that j is increasing? So on loop 'N', we have T[j+1]. But on loop N+1 that will be T[j]! We can save some of our intermediate results, if we don't mind changing the sign. That is, `T[j+1] - T[j]` will eventually become `T[j] - T[j-1]`. And if we just negated it, it would be `T[j-1] - T[j]`, which we want to keep!

What's more, if we can save that computation, we won't need `T_new` any more, because the only reason for `T_new` was because `T[j-1]` got updated before we could use it to compute `T[j]`.

Let's try saving the `T[j+1] - T[j]` computation, and negating it.

```
saved = T[1] - T[0]
for j in range(1, num_nodes+1):
    T[j] = (T[j]
           + -saved * adt_per_dx2
           + (T[j+1] - T[j]) * adt_per_dx2
           )
    saved = T[j+1] - T[j]
```

Okay, that worked a little. And it got rid of the `T_new` variable. Can we do more? Let's add one more temp variable, and multiply:

```
saved = (T[1] - T[0]) * adt_per_dx2

for j in range(1, num_items+1):
    temp = (T[j+1] - T[j]) * adt_per_dx2
    T[j] += temp - saved
    saved = temp
```

And let's print the time, with the current T array:

```
print("Time={}s, T={}r\n".format(time_sec, T))
```

Putting it all together:

```
num_nodes = int(input("Enter the number of nodes: "))
boundary1 = float(input("Enter the first boundary condition: "))
boundary2 = float(input("Enter the second boundary condition: "))
conductivity = float(input("Enter the thermal conductivity: "))
initial_cond = float(input("Enter the initial condition: "))
num_ticks = int(input("Enter the number of time steps: "))
delta_t = float(input("Enter the change in time, dT: "))

T = ( [boundary1]
    + [initial_cond] * num_nodes
    + [boundary2]
    )

adt_per_dx2 = conductivity * delta_t * (num_nodes + 1)**2

time_sec = 0.0
for t in range(num_ticks):
    time_sec += delta_t

    saved = (T[1] - T[0]) * adt_per_dx2

    for j in range(1, num_nodes+1):
        temp = (T[j+1] - T[j]) * adt_per_dx2
        T[j] += temp - saved
        saved = temp

    print("Time={}s, T={}r\n".format(time_sec, T))
```

Now, when I run it there's a problem. I think the "adt_per_dx2" is supposed to be less-than-1. And it's not. Which means that the delta-T between nodes is increased, and that increased number added to T[j]. Which I know is wrong, because you don't get free heat from nowhere.

But this is the part where I don't actually know what you're doing. So I don't know where the mistake is. I think it has to do with the number of nodes, and maybe you should ask for a total length or thickness and divide by number of nodes? Anyway, check it out and see what you make of it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is the reason, but when using `floats` in conditions, never use `!=`. Instead, use `<=`. Indeed, a difference of 0.000001 is sufficient for your condition never to be true and in your code you do mostly steps of 1.0.

So if your input `i` is not round, your first `while` loop will run forever.